# Changes in legend marker size are NOT preserved when saving to png in Matlab 2014b. Is there a way to do it?

Tags: matlab, png, legend

I can increase the marker size in the legend like this:

```
[~,icons,~,~]=legend('Data1','Data2','Data3');

for k = 4:6
  icons(k).Children.MarkerSize = 15;
end
```

But when I save the figure to -png format the marker size in the legend goes back to the default size. When I save to -pdf format the changes are preserved. Am I missing something obvious or is it more complicated? Any suggestions on how can I preserve the changes when I am saving to -png?

Comment: How do you save it?

Comment: The problem is with Matlab2014b because when I tried with Matlab2016a the problem doesn't exist. It seems to be a bug then.. Can someone  suggest a way to fix this bug in Matlab2014b (if it's possible), please?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I tried also with functions like "saveas" or "exportfig" or even manually, but the problem persists. In Matlab 2016a the problem is fixed.

Comment: Show us how do you save it

Comment: a=1:10;
b=1:10;
scatter(a,b);
[~,hobj,~,~]=legend('Test');
M = findobj(hobj,'type','patch');
set(M,'MarkerSize',13);
saveas(gcf,'test.png');

Comment: I'm having the same issue, even when saving as a PDF, with the command `print(figHnd, 'test.pdf', '-dpdf')`. I'm also using 2014b and can not easily update to a newer version. Does anyone know a work around for this issue?